# Updating parameter in SwingWorker

Tags: java, swingworker, jprogressbar

I need some help, I'm making a program like a file manager.  In my program I need to make simultaneous files copies.  For that I use `SwingWorker` to see the progress of the copies in a `JProgressbar`, but I need to know how to add more files to Copy in the task with the same destination.

This is my class that extends from `Swingworker` in my principal program I´ll select some files or folders to copy in one destination.  What I need is while the `Copytask` is working I can to add more files to the `Copyitem Arraylist`.

Please help and sorry about my english.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import xray.XRAYView;


public class CopyTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer>
    {

        ArrayList<CopyItem>copia;
        private long totalBytes = 0L;
        private long copiedBytes = 0L;
        JProgressBar progressAll;
        JProgressBar progressCurrent;
        boolean override=true;
        boolean overrideall=false;


        public CopyTask(ArrayList<CopyItem>copia,JProgressBar progressAll,JProgressBar progressCurrent)
        {

            this.copia=copia;
            this.progressAll=progressAll;
            this.progressCurrent=progressCurrent;


            progressAll.setValue(0);
            progressCurrent.setValue(0);
            totalBytes=retrieveTotalBytes(copia);

        }

        public void AgregarCopia(ArrayList<CopyItem>addcopia)throws Exception{

          copia.addAll(copia.size(), addcopia);
          totalBytes=retrieveTotalBytes(addcopia)+totalBytes;
          System.out.println("AL AGREGAR: "+copia.size()+" Tamaño"+totalBytes);



        }

        public File getDriveDest(){
        File dest=new File(copia.get(0).getOrigen().getPath().split("\\")[0]);
        return dest;
        }


        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() throws Exception
        {


            for(CopyItem cop:copia){

             File ori=cop.getOrigen();
             File des=new File(cop.getDestino().getPath());
             if(!des.exists()){
              des.mkdirs();
             }
             if(!overrideall){
             override =true;
             }
             File para=new File(cop.getDestino().getPath()+"\\"+ori.getName());
             copyFiles(ori, para);

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void process(List<Integer> chunks)
        {
            for(int i : chunks)
            {
                progressCurrent.setValue(i);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void done()
        {
            setProgress(100);

        }

        private long retrieveTotalBytes(ArrayList<CopyItem>fich)
        {
           long size=0;
            for(CopyItem cop: fich)
            {
                size += cop.getOrigen().length();

            }

            return size;
        }






private void copyFiles(File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws IOException

         {
                    if(overrideall==false){
                      if(targetFile.exists() && !targetFile.isDirectory()){

                          String []options={"Si a Todos","Si","No a Ninguno","No"};
                          int seleccion=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "El fichero \n"+targetFile+" \n se encuentra en el equipo, \n¿Desea sobreescribirlo?", "Colisión de ficheros", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, null);

                          switch(seleccion){
                              case 0:
                              override=true;
                              overrideall=true;
                              break;
                              case 1:
                              override=true;
                              overrideall=false;
                              break;
                              case 2:
                              override =false;
                              overrideall=true;
                              break;
                              case 3:
                              override =false;
                              overrideall=false;
                              break;

                          }

                      }

                    }

                    if(override || !targetFile.exists()){
                    FileInputStream LeeOrigen= new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

                    OutputStream Salida = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int tamaño;

                    long fileBytes = sourceFile.length();

                    long totalBytesCopied = 0; 

                    while ((tamaño = LeeOrigen.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                    Salida.write(buffer, 0, tamaño);

                     totalBytesCopied += tamaño;
                     copiedBytes+= tamaño;

                     setProgress((int)Math.round(((double)copiedBytes++ / (double)totalBytes) * 100));

                     int progress = (int)Math.round(((double)totalBytesCopied / (double)fileBytes) * 100);

                     publish(progress);



                    }


                    Salida.close();
                    LeeOrigen.close();



                publish(100);
                }


            }
        }
```

Here is CopyItem class

```
import java.io.File;


public class CopyItem {
    File origen;
    File destino;
    String root;

    public CopyItem(File origen, File destino) {
        this.origen = origen;
        this.destino = destino;
    }

    public CopyItem(File origen, File destino, String root) {
        this.origen = origen;
        this.destino = destino;
        this.root = root;
    }

    public String getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(String root) {
        this.root = root;
    }


    public File getOrigen() {
        return origen;
    }

    public void setOrigen(File origen) {
        this.origen = origen;
    }

    public File getDestino() {
        return destino;
    }

    public void setDestino(File destino) {
        this.destino = destino;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


}
```

Comment: I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add the files directly to source List(the list contains files to be copied ) but you need to synchronize your code because adding more file will be in different thread(UI Thread),another way is to implement (produce/consumer ) using [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Consumer class run in separate Thread or Swingworker coping files is in progress.
Producer class runs UI Thread (selecting more files).

both should have access to BlockingQueue (contains files to be copied)(of course BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe based on the documentation.  ,it has the advantage to block the execution and wait for the files to be added this is very useful if you dont know when the files are added )

I prefer using Thread Pool to manage the threads executions(Optional).

Comment: Thanks a lot Amjad, i had hear about (produce/consumer) but i don´t know how to implement that in this case, i think the idea is in one Threat listening for new addes files which send the other threat to copy, but i don´t know how send a copy and wait ultil the copy is ended to send other, thanks in advance.